# Different components in different rows of an Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-calendar

I am new to Android. I would like to create an `Activity` very similar to "Add event" part of Android Calendar app. To me it looks like a `ListView` with different components in each row. I could be wrong. If I am right, I still don't know how to add different components to each row of a `ListView`, e.g., `EditText` in one row, `TextView` in another row, etc. If this app is not `ListView` at all, if anybody can tell me how I can create something similar, I'd appreciate that a lot.

Comment: For now, I think for my purposes, creating a ListView with Custom Adapter is an overkill. If I decide to actually put different types of components in different rows of a ListView for some other reasons, I will follow rickyalbert link to see where it leads me and will update this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

hello  check this link it be helpful [1](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

[listView  with different component](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to learn how to implement a custom Adapter (see this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown)

Then in your getView overriden method (you'll learn about it in the tutorial) you have to do something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = null;
    if (position == LAYOUT1_POSITION) //In this row you will place the layout named layout1
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowLayout1, parent, false);
    if (position == LAYOUT2_POSITION)
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowLayout2, parent, false);
    //Do similar for all your different layouts

    return rowView;
}
```